# How to vertically align an image inside a <h1> tag

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<h1>abc abc<span><img class="goldT" src="btns/nav02.png"></span></h1>
```

css

```
h1{
    margin:15px 0 15px 20px;
    font-size:1.1rem;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#e1e1e1;
    padding-left:10px;
    color: #444444;
}
h1 span{
    float:right;
    margin-right:14px;
}
h1 .goldT{
    width:140px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

How can I keep img `goldT` vertically centered with header text `abc`.

[**Here is the FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKgYa/)

Comment: Question is awesome.....

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Use margin-top. Ex : `margin-top: -13px;`

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/KKgYa/9/)

Comment: This can't be an answer, if the Height of the `h1` is more then how it will affect check this http://jsfiddle.net/KKgYa/11/

Answer (score 16):

Try:

HTML:

```
<h1>
    <span class="text">abc abc</span><span class="span">
        <img class="goldT" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
    </span>
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.span, .text {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
h1 {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKgYa/10/)

Answer (score 4):

A much simpler solution is as follows:

`<h1><span>abc abc</span><img class="goldT" src="btns/nav02.png"></h1>`

On the h1 set a `line-height` and on the image and span set a `vertical-align:middle;`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this here we can make image vertically center

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/SxxWV/10/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
<div class="box"><img  src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
</div>   
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main{ height:500px; border:1px red solid;position:relative}
.box{width:40px; height:40px; background:transparent; }

/* for centering */
img{width:100px}
.box { display: inline-block; width:100px }
.main{ text-align: center; }
.main:after{ content: ""; display: inline-block; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit 2023/03/03:

There are better ways to align elements nowadays:

```
h1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

CSS Grid can be used too, although I don't think it is best suited in this situation.

---

Original answer:

Just wrap text together with image into `<span>`:

```
<h1>
    <span>
        abc abc
        <img class="goldT" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">    
    </span>
</h1>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KKgYa/7/)

Comment: Morpheus, it this case text `abc` is not on the left side of header. Text should be on left and img on the right side.

Comment: In that case wrap text and image into separate `span` and float them. Example -> http://jsfiddle.net/KKgYa/13/

Answer (score 0):

you need to set css display style and vertical-align for the `<h1>`

see demo :http://jsfiddle.net/BhaveshKachhadiya/REHLZ/3/embedded/result/

Css for **h1** :

```
h1{
    margin:15px 0 15px 20px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:1.1rem;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#e1e1e1;
    padding-left:10px;
    color: #444444;
}
```